# meaning of for as a preposition

Tags: prepositions, usage

> Do you want bacon and eggs for breakfast?

I'm not sure about the meaning of **for** here. So I just found this explanation from the Collins dictionary:

> If you do something for a particular occasion, you do it on that
> occasion or to celebrate that occasion.

Can this be used to explain the 'for' above?

Comment: It's not listed by Collins, but 'have [a type of food] for [a meal]' is a very common use of 'for'.  _What shall we have for tea today?_

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for) has this: ***2 a** as being or constituting*, with the example, *eggs for breakfast*

Comment: for is always a preposition.

Answer (score 1):

Although the examples given in the [Collins definition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/for) are of holidays/celebratory occasions, this also applies to everyday "occasions" including rituals such as meals.

"For" is the normal way to associate a kind of food with a particular meal (or part of a meal) in which it is eaten:

- What are you having **for** breakfast/dessert?

Just as breakfast may involve different foods on different days, regular homework assignments in a class differ in their specific contents:

- **For** your homework today, read chapter 3.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use that expression to explain the **for** in that sentence.

In this case:

> Do you want bacon and eggs **for** breakfast?

In this sentence the *for* involves that *you are doing bacon and eggs* for the particular occasion of that breakfast, because I will assume that "you" don't normally eat bacon and eggs at breakfast, so it is actually a "special occasion".

Or you can interpret that *for breakfast* as only a single breakfast, so just in that specific occasion(that breakfast) you will *eat bacon and eggs*

Comment: It doesn't imply a special occasion - we might just as easily say "I only had toast for breakfast".

Comment: exactly! But in this case you eat *bacon and eggs* in a specific occasion: **breakfast**

Comment: But not a _special_ occasion - you might have it for breakfast every day!

Comment: I agree with you, in this case it might not be a special occasion. I think that in this sentence the *for* will better suits this part of the explenation by the dictionary: "you do it on that occasion" (in that specific breakfast that might not be a special one)